# How to update record in Insert into Select query

Tags: sql-server

I have this query which I am using to insert date in a table via select query.

```
INSERT INTO TEST
SELECT * FROM (SELECT myDate, EmpCode, '2020-04-11 09:10:21', '2020-04-11 18:47:56') TBL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE myDate = TBL.myDate AND EmpCode = TBL.EmpCode)
```

The date this query might generate will be

```
Date          EmpCode  Check In               Check Out
2020-04-11    101      2020-04-11 09:10:21    2020-04-11 18:47:56
```

So if I try to add same record it won't add in the `TEST` table but if I change the Values it will. Lets assume `EmpCode` is 101 and `myDate` is `GETDATE()`. Now for same date and same employee if I change the value of any column, here first `datetime` is `Check In` and second one is `Check Out`, so if I update the Check Out to `'2020-04-11 18:19:32'`, I want to not insert any row in the table but to update the existing row with new values. What are the changes I am supposed to make to make this work. The out after executing the query with updated value should be

```
Date          EmpCode  Check In               Check Out
2020-04-11    101      2020-04-11 09:10:21    2020-04-11 18:19:32
```

Comment: This subquery is incomplete (missing FROM and table): 
(SELECT myDate, EmpCode, '2020-04-11 09:10:21', '2020-04-11 18:47:56')
Are you trying to retrieve data from another table here? 
Those are the values that will enter as insert or update in TEST table?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `MERGE` statement.

```
MERGE TEST AS TARGET
    USING (SELECT myDate, EmpCode, '2020-04-11 09:10:21' AS check_in, '2020-04-11 18:47:56' AS check_out) AS SOURCE
-- Replace it with with actual source query. this is just an exmaple.
ON TARGET.EmpCode = SOURCE.EmpCode
AND TARGET.myDate = SOURCE.myDate
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET 
        check_in = SOURCE.check_in
        , check_out = SOURCE.check_out
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT (myDate, EmpCode, check_in, check_out)
         VALUES (SOURCE.myDate, SOURCE.EmpCode, SOURCE.check_in, SOURCE.check_out);
```

You can explore more about `MERGE` from [here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-merge/) or from [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).